# How could I see by the event viewer log that the format of date was changed?

Tags: windows, windows-event-log, eventviewer

I need to see by the eventviewer log that the format of date was changed.

I know that have the eventlog of ID 4616, but it's for DATE changing, and not lot when I just change the FORMAT of the date.

The environment is a Windows 2008 server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you are looking for Event Id 3000 in the International\Operational event log.  It's probably called International due to the control panel name (intl.cpl).

[image]

Comment: Good one, I wouldn't have thought this is being logged by Windows!

Comment: Very nice! It's exactly what I am needing!